# What's the meaning of docker hub's url design?

Tags: url, docker

`https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/`

There is a `_` in the url before the product name.

What is it for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have a account on `dockerhub` called `foobar`:

```
# pull from your account (foobar)
docker pull foobar/ubuntu:latest
```

Otherwise, if you omit the username:

```
# pull from the official account (library)
docker pull ubuntu:latest
# almost the same as
docker pull library/ubuntu:latest
```

The underscore(`_`) is a special namespace used to publish the official repositories.

https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/ is almost the same as https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/library/ubuntu/

---

The only difference is that you will get different image-names with identical image-id:

```
$ docker pull ubuntu:latest
$ docker pull library/ubuntu:latest
$ docker images

REPOSITORY                                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
library/ubuntu                            latest              86ce37374f40        7 days ago          192.7 MB
ubuntu                                    latest              86ce37374f40        7 days ago          192.7 MB
```

Comment: This just helped me out, so I'm commenting in case other followers seek the same information. If you're using a self-hosted docker registry (2.1.1) with the pull-through cache, you must use localhost:5000/library/ubuntu instead of localhost:5000/ubuntu.